# HTTP_REFERER not getting saved in a session

Tags: php, session, http-referer

I know HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed, but it does the job perfectly the way we want it now. Except I can't get the first referrer to be saved in a session, so entering from domain.com works, but going to another page will be blocked cause the HTTP_REFERER changes into our own domain. Below is my code hopefully someone can help me out.

```
<?php
// Start the session
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
?>

<?php
// Getting referer and saving
$server = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
$referer = parse_url($server);
$refererhost = isset($referer['host']) ? $referer['host'] : '';
$_SESSION['originalref'] = $refererhost;
?>

<?php if ($_SESSION['originalref'] == 'domain.com'): ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Allowed.</p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php else: ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Not allowed. Debug: <?= $_SESSION['originalref'] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Edit: I made the HTML output in the statements simpler, normally a complete site will be loaded and this is the root template.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but what is not working? What result do you get on running this? Does HTTP_REFERER getting really set, did you echo it for testing purpose?

Comment: It's getting set, but not saved in a session. So at first entering the website from domain.com works, but browsing on the website doesn't since HTTP_REFERER is changed into our own domain as soon as you change pages.

Comment: _“Except I can't get the first referrer to be saved in a session”_ - I can’t see you even _try_ anywhere? The only thing I see you put in the session here is `$_SESSION['originalref'] = $refererhost` - but you are overwriting that value every time, you are not checking if it is maybe set already …

Comment: Ah that makes sense! So I need to check if $_SESSION['originalref'] is already set? Otherwise it will of course overrule the session every new visit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it because @04FS pointed me in the right direction and also @davidev thanks for your time. The solution was to check if the session is already set, otherwise it will be overwritten every page, so I have added the following:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['originalref'])){

    $_SESSION['originalref'] = $refererhost;

}
```

And now its working!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my own server. I am setting the referer from a HTML file and calling a php file.

`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` works indeed - I get ..../test.html.

After that I save that value directly into the Session variable like you did.

`$_SESSION['originalref2'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Important: on another page you need to start the Session first, then you can use the Session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['originalref2'];

?>
```

Will output the correct referer link.

Comment: Thanks for checking. This part is indeed working, but after visiting more pages it will override the session. Like @04fs is saying I need to check if a session is already set.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry I didn't understand it in the first way. It is getting override because the method is called again. - As you mentioned store a value in session if the referer was already set.

Answer (score -1):

You can user $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the exact domain.

Comment: This will give the URL of your own Server. He is trying to get the URL from where the user is coming.

Comment: Hi Hema, SERVER_NAME returns the domain name of the website itself, not from the referrer as far as I know? Edit: @davidev was quicker :)

Comment: Okay.. I misunderstood question. 

Then at first need to check for referer, if it is not empty and the domain not equal to our domain, then we have to consider it as referal.